# Installing Luvit on an openshift server

Tags: lua, luvit

I can't seem to use luvit at all on the server. It is installed on the machine I am connecting from. I attempted to install luvit via the commands, but it said permissions denied. The info on Openshift's blogpost is out of date, heavily. 2013-level heavily.